# How do you set a registration form email link to open the link in the original browser tab?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I set up a registration system which requires clicking on a link in email to confirm/activate the account. It looks like:

```
$textContent .= "Dear John,\n\n
Thank you for registering with YourBusinessName. 
To complete registration click on the activation link:
\n\n
<a href='https://www.your-website.abc/activate-account' target='_blank'>activate</a>";
```

This works however when you click on the email link it always opens in a new browser tab (or window depending on preferences). This leaves a confusing extra, lame, window in a tab.

How do you make it either open in the original tab/window or perhaps open while simultaneously killing the original tab?

Comment: One important thing to understand is that, regardless of what `target` attribute you set, email clients can override it: nothing you do will matter to X% of your recipients.

Comment: I use Thunderbird it has no concept of tabs. All email clients will open in a new tab or window regardless of `target=""`

Comment: Thanks both. I also use Thunderbird and I also use gmail's webmail to do testing. This is what I am experiencing. However, my client has made this request and it seems like a nice idea. With the million dollar service like FB, LI, Tw, etc will it work the same way, new tab/window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you get a problem to solve in your head and you fail to see the obvious. The core problem is to keep from having new windows open when attempting to confirm a registration form.

The answer is to provide a confirmation code in the email message rather than a link and instruct the visitor to copy the code into the confirmation page on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove target attribute from your link:

```
<a href='https://www.your-website.abc/activate-account'>activate</a>";
```

Or set it to `target="_self"`:

```
<a href='https://www.your-website.abc/activate-account' target="_self">activate</a>";
```

Specification of the attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: Thank you but these options do not work with links clicked on in an email message. I've tried: no target, _self, _parent, _blank, a target with a custom id (same as the registration page) like _911.